# Issue with Workbench setting

Tags: users, workflows, workbench

I'm creating workflow for my Drupal 7 site. On this site we installed Workbench, Workbench Access, Workbench Moderation and Workbench Media. I'm following [this setting](https://www.drupal.org/node/1175592), but still having 2 issues with Workbench.

1) My drafts are not showing on "My Drafts" tab. It only show if I give the permission "Bypass content access control", which I dont want to do that.

2) I wanna hide "All Recent Content" on My Content tab. Currently, it how Logout page, and Thank you for creting an account page, which I dont wanna show these too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can give you this answer, check your permissions against what is typical in the documentation page you listed. Have you checked this page selecting the given Role you want to examine:

> If non-administrative users encounter access denied (403) errors or
>   fail to see notifications about moderation states, the "Check
>   permissions" tab can help you determine what permissions are missing.
>   Visit:
>
> Admin > Configuration > Workbench > Workbench Moderation > Check
>   Permissions

The *My Content* page in Workbench Moderation is a View. You can customize its filters or conditions to meet your needs -- but be careful it's provided by the Workbench module so if you update the module you will likely loose your changes to the View unless you implement your changes using `hook_views_default_alter`.

Comment: Thank tenken. Good to know "All Recent Content" is a View.

Comment: I found out why not showing my drafts on My Drafts tab. Actually, the module "Workbench" has a conflict with "Content Access" module.

Comment: hmm I think you're refering to https://www.drupal.org/node/1902208 I would be careful saying it's a `conflict` persay. Anytime you have multiple content access schemes per node you're basically asking for trouble. But, it does sound like theres a simple views name or path conflict between these 2 modules.